# How do I detect the presence of a pattern in a string, for a fixed set of patterns?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, purrr, dplyr, tidymodels

In the context of variable selection, I'm trying to count the number of times a variable is selected over bootstrapped iterations. A simple version of the problem is provided below, along with my solution (`answer`). But my solution quickly becomes unwieldy when dealing with 50 or 100 variables.

I have the set of variable names I would like to count over (`pred`) so I thought it should be possible to create new columns based on those values and then detect the relevant string for each. But I can't figure out how without manually setting the column names and pasting the function. There must be a better way...

Any other solutions would be welcome, including tidyverse or purrr...

```
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars
n <- nrow(df)
pred <- colnames(df)[2:length(df)]
target <- "mpg"
mpg_formula <- paste(target, "~", paste(pred, collapse = "+"))

steplm <- data.frame()

bootnum <- 10

for (i in 1:bootnum) {
  message("Fitting model ", i, " out of ", bootnum)
  data.id <- sample(1:dim(df)[1], replace = T)
  fit.lms <- step(lm(mpg_formula, data=df[data.id, ]), 
                  direction = "backward",
                  trace = 0)
  selected.vars <- paste(sort(names(coef(fit.lms)[-1])), collapse = ", ")
  step.result <- data.frame("model" = selected.vars,
                            "nvar" = length(names(coef(fit.lms)[-1])))
  steplm <- dplyr::bind_rows(steplm, step.result)
}

steplm %>%
  transmute(
      steplm %>%
  transmute(
      cyl = grepl(pattern = "cyl",  x = model),
     disp = grepl(pattern = "disp", x = model),
       hp = grepl(pattern = "hp",   x = model),
     drat = grepl(pattern = "drat", x = model),
       wt = grepl(pattern = "wt",   x = model),
     qsec = grepl(pattern = "qsec", x = model),
       vs = grepl(pattern = "vs",   x = model),
       am = grepl(pattern = "am",   x = model),
     gear = grepl(pattern = "gear", x = model),
     carb = grepl(pattern = "carb", x = model)
  ) -> answer
```

This produces the following data.frame (or matrix), from which I can just sum the columns to get the values I want (or do matrix operations to get pairwise and joint dependencies between terms). This is just to point out the matrix format is needed for the next step...

```
     cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
    TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
    TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
    TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
   FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
   FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
    TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply` :

```
sapply(pred, grepl, steplm$model)

#        cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [6,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [7,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [8,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [9,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[10,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

`sapply` returns a matrix. You can wrap `data.frame` to `sapply` output if you need dataframe.

```
identical(data.frame(sapply(pred, grepl, steplm$model)), answer)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider taking a different approach to your bootstrap resampling, [more similar to this](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/statistics/bootstrap/).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rsample)
library(broom)

car_boot <- bootstraps(mtcars, times = 100)
car_boot
#> # Bootstrap sampling 
#> # A tibble: 100 x 2
#>    splits          id          
#>    <list>          <chr>       
#>  1 <split [32/10]> Bootstrap001
#>  2 <split [32/12]> Bootstrap002
#>  3 <split [32/12]> Bootstrap003
#>  4 <split [32/12]> Bootstrap004
#>  5 <split [32/13]> Bootstrap005
#>  6 <split [32/9]>  Bootstrap006
#>  7 <split [32/11]> Bootstrap007
#>  8 <split [32/10]> Bootstrap008
#>  9 <split [32/13]> Bootstrap009
#> 10 <split [32/14]> Bootstrap010
#> # … with 90 more rows

fit_mpg <- function(split) {
  step(lm(mpg ~ ., data = analysis(split)), direction = "backward", trace = 0)
}

boot_models <- car_boot %>%
  mutate(model = map(splits, fit_mpg),
         coef_info = map(model, tidy))


boot_coefs <- boot_models %>% 
  unnest(coef_info)

boot_coefs
#> # A tibble: 645 x 8
#>    splits       id         model term     estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#>    <list>       <chr>      <lis> <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 <split [32/… Bootstrap… <lm>  (Interc…  6.16      7.09        0.868   3.93e-1
#>  2 <split [32/… Bootstrap… <lm>  drat      1.89      1.44        1.31    2.01e-1
#>  3 <split [32/… Bootstrap… <lm>  wt       -1.92      0.738      -2.61    1.50e-2
#>  4 <split [32/… Bootstrap… <lm>  qsec      0.754     0.307       2.45    2.12e-2
#>  5 <split [32/… Bootstrap… <lm>  am        3.80      1.49        2.55    1.70e-2
#>  6 <split [32/… Bootstrap… <lm>  carb     -0.859     0.407      -2.11    4.47e-2
#>  7 <split [32/… Bootstrap… <lm>  (Interc…  8.51      4.05        2.10    4.48e-2
#>  8 <split [32/… Bootstrap… <lm>  disp      0.00752   0.00474     1.59    1.25e-1
#>  9 <split [32/… Bootstrap… <lm>  wt       -1.17      0.708      -1.66    1.09e-1
#> 10 <split [32/… Bootstrap… <lm>  gear      5.37      0.757       7.10    1.25e-7
#> # … with 635 more rows

boot_coefs %>%
  select(id, term) %>%
  filter(term != "(Intercept)") %>%
  mutate(value = TRUE) %>%
  complete(id, term, fill = list(value = FALSE)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = term, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 100 x 11
#>    id           am    carb  cyl   disp  drat  gear  hp    qsec  vs    wt   
#>    <chr>        <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#>  1 Bootstrap001 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#>  2 Bootstrap002 FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
#>  3 Bootstrap003 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#>  4 Bootstrap004 FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#>  5 Bootstrap005 FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
#>  6 Bootstrap006 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE 
#>  7 Bootstrap007 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#>  8 Bootstrap008 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#>  9 Bootstrap009 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#> 10 Bootstrap010 FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
#> # … with 90 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>